# o.Subject is not a constructor - Angular 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular10

**Ng serve** and **ng build --prod** command working fine, but when I deploy the app on serve that time below error occurs:-

```
TypeError: o.Subject is not a constructor
at new e (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Object.useFactory (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Object.i [as factory] (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Xo.hydrate (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Xo.get (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Jf.get (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Object.get (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Gn (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Module.Sl (vendor-esnext.js:1)
at Mn.e.ɵfac [as factory] (vendor-esnext.js:1)
```

---

**tsconfig.base.json**

```
{"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": "",
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"declaration": false,
"downlevelIteration": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [
  "dom",
  "es2017"
],
"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "ESNext",
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": [
    "node_modules/@angular/*"
  ]
}},"include": [
"src/**/*.ts",
"node_modules/ng4-fittext/*.d.ts"],"exclude": [],"compileOnSave": false,}
```

Comment: I think you need to check the import statements for `Subject`. It must be imported like `import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject"; `. Your project contains an import statement for `Subject` from somewhere else.

Comment: With the new angular10 version, the rxjs compat is removed and thus `Subject` should be imported from `import { Subject } from 'rxjs';` (not from `rxjs/Subject`)

Comment: Great. I learned a new think about `Angular 10 & Rxjs 6`. Thanks for the correction.  @PoulKruijt

Comment: I have used imports as mentioned. But I am still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: you can reproduce same with using command  `ng serve --prod` . No need to create build every time to check it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem will be solved in Angular 10 and later if you replace the `import` statement of
subject as below.

Replace:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
```

with:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
```

Comment: Same goes for import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'. This should also be replaced with import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

Comment: did not work for me!
I used `import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 1):

If you come here to fix problem with angular-2-dropdown-multiselect, just update to the latest version.(actually 1.9.0).

Answer (score 1):

This error can occur due to outdated packages. If you have fixed the imports in all the project source files, then check inside the `node_modules` folder and find the packages which use `rxjs/Subject`. It will get fixed after updating those packages to their latest compatible versions.

In my case, it was due to the package `aws-amplify-angular` with Angular 10. Updating it and `aws-amplify` to the latest version solved the issue.

Tip: To find the libraries with old imports do a global search in the `node_modules` folder